# HTML code injection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html-parsing

I have a simple html snippet that I add to the document during runtime. I am using jQuery's selectors but that should irrelevant to the issue I am facing.

When using:
$("#elementID").html()

The code is displayed but with no CSS applied. The behaviour make sense since the CSS has already been loaded and applied.

My questions are:
- Is there away to "refresh" a DOM element in order to re-apply CSS on it after its html content has been changed?
- or is there a way to apply CSS on the code I have in the JavaScript before adding it to the DOM element?

I am aware of various JS\html templates library but at this stage I am trying to minimize the dependency on extra libraries, specially since that the snippets I am generating\injecting are very simple and I dont mind them staying in the JS code

Jamil

Comment: no it does not make sense, css rules are applied "on runtime" (css does not change how to browser displays html, its defined by it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong. CSS is applied all the time (during runtime) - look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2zTn/2/) example. You messed up with something else.

Comment: I am simple appending the html content to a DOM element. Using the following: $("#<elementID>").html(<htmlcontent>); The HTML content contains jQuery markup but still the displayer output is not picking up the jQuery styles. Would it make a difference if I created a DOM element and appended it to one of the elements existing in the page instead of injecting HTML ?

Comment: I have tried jsFiddle and still getting the incorrect rendering. Can you have a look at the code I am trying to render. In jsFiddle: $('div#new').html('<form><div id=\"radio\"><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio1\" name=\"radio\" /><label for=\"radio1\">Choice 1</label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio2\" name=\"radio\" /><label for=\"radio2\">Choice 2</label><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio3\" name=\"radio\" /><label for=\"radio3\">Choice 3</label></div></form>');

Comment: Ok it seems that the problem I am facing is jQuery related rather than CSS\Javascipt. I am closing this question and starting a new one with the jQuery problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure css is not applied? Because it should be. If you add a new element to the DOM, it should just take on the styling from any css files you have loaded. How are you applying the css?

Comment: I am not trying to apply the CSS. I am inject the html into one of the existing DOM elements . This injected code is displayed but doesn't pick up any of the CSS properties that it should. I tried testing the generated html code in a separate page by hardcoding it in the html and it picks up all the CSS operties. The problem only happens when I inject the html code dynamically using: $("#<elementID>").html(<htmlcontent>)

Comment: Ok it seems that the problem I am facing is jQuery related rather than CSS\Javascipt. I am closing this question and starting a new one with the jQuery problem

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger('create')` on the element will force a re-rendering of the element if needed